# Reading multiple numbers from a text file

Tags: python, text, python-3.x, numbers

I am new to programming in python and need help doing this.

I have a text file with several numbers like this:

```
12 35 21
123 12 15
12 18 89
```

I need to be able to read the individual numbers of each line to be able to use them in mathematical formulas.

Comment: `[map(float, ln.split()) for ln in open("filename") if ln.strip()]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In python, you read a line from a file as a string.  You can then work with the string to get the data you need:

```
with open("datafile") as f:
    for line in f:  #Line is a string
        #split the string on whitespace, return a list of numbers 
        # (as strings)
        numbers_str = line.split()
        #convert numbers to floats
        numbers_float = [float(x) for x in numbers_str]  #map(float,numbers_str) works too
```

I've done it all in a bunch of steps, but you'll often see people combine them:

```
with open('datafile') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers_float = map(float, line.split())
        #work with numbers_float here
```

---

Finally, using them in a mathematical formula is easy too.  First, create a function:

```
def function(x,y,z):
    return x+y+z
```

Now iterate through your file calling the function:

```
with open('datafile') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers_float = map(float, line.split())
        print function(numbers_float[0],numbers_float[1],numbers_float[2])
        #shorthand:  print function(*numbers_float)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it is by using `numpy`'s function called `loadtxt`.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("datafile")
first_row = data[:,0]
second_row = data[:,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you name your file numbers.txt

```
def get_numbers_from_file(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, "r")
    strnumbers = file.read().split()
    return map(int, strnumbers)


print get_numbers_from_file("numbers.txt")
```

this must return [12, 35, 21, 123, 12, 15, 12, 18, 89]
after you can choose individuly every numbers with list_variable[intergrer]

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work

```
f = open('somefile.txt','r')
arrayList = []
for line in f.readlines():
    arrayList.extend(line.split())
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the file name as your argument at the command line, then you can do the following:

```
    from sys import argv

    input_file = argv[1]
    with open(input_file,"r") as input_data:
        A= [map(int,num.split()) for num in input_data.readlines()]

    print A #read out your imported data
```

otherwise you can do this:

```
    from os.path import dirname

    with open(dirname(__file__) + '/filename.txt') as input_data:
        A= [map(int,num.split()) for num in input_data.readlines()]

    print A
```